# Every combination with all lengths of array

Tags: ruby, arrays, combinations

I want all combinations from an array, also in combination with capitalized and in all length (two combinations, three combinations and so on ...)

My script looks like:

my array

```
a = ["hello", "my", "world"]
```

this adds capitalized words to our array, do not want to repeat the words

```
b = a.map(&:capitalize)
```

this combines the words with capitalized

```
c = [[a, b]]
```

this should print my combinations

```
puts c.first.product(*c[1..-1]).map(&:join)
```

the result is

```
hellomyworld

HelloMyWorld
```

this is not what i wanted. I want

```
hellomyworld
Hellomyworld
HelloMyworld
HelloMyWorld
helloMyworld
helloMyWorld
hellomyWorld
HellomyWorld
```

and so on. (do not know if i have missed a combination) does anybody have a glue?

Comment: by **in combination with capitalized and in all length** did you mean that `hello`, `hellomy`, ... should also be in your result set?

Comment: yes, all words from the array in the order which is given, but mixexd with all possibilities of downcase, capitalize ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This would do what you requested:

```
a.map { |word| [word, word.capitalize] }
 .reduce(&:product)
 .map { |sentence| sentence.flatten.join }
```

First, we map the word array to an array of word pairs: the original and the capitalized version. Then we reduce these pairs into a sentence array by taking the product of the previously collected sentences with the next word pair: this produces uneven arrays like [["hello", "my"], "world"] but that is not a problem because in the next step we flatten and join each sentence into a single string. I hope this helps.

---

Edit: I just realized that your solution almost works as well: insted of `c = [[a, b]]` you should make it `c = a.zip b`. `zip` pairs the respective elements with each other, while `[]` puts the given arrays into an outer array.

Answer (score 1):

```
["hello", "my", "world"]
.map{|w| [w, w.capitalize]}
.tap{|first, *rest| break first.product(*rest).map(&:join)}
```